# Get ID of which ID sortable replaced

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my current code, which all works. The issue is that I need to find out which ID was replaced, not the index. So for instance, if you move Item 3 to Item 5, I need the Start variable to be 127 and the End variable to be 129 for example. How do I alter my code to get this information?

```
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    alert("Start position: " + ui.item.startPos);
    alert("New position: " + ui.item.index());
    alert("Item Moved: " + $(ui.item).attr('id'));
    var start = ui.item.startPos;
    var end = ui.item.index();
    var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
             data: (start, end, id),
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'update_order.php?start='+start+'&end='+end+'&id='+id+''
             });
}
});
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

});

```
<ul id="sortable"> 
    <li class="ui" id="125"><span></span>Item 1</li> 
    <li class="ui" id="126"><span></span>Item 2</li> 
    <li class="ui" id="127"><span></span>Item 3</li> 
    <li class="ui" id="128"><span></span>Item 4</li> 
    <li class="ui" id="129"><span></span>Item 5</li> 
    <li class="ui" id="130"><span></span>Item 6</li> 
    <li class="ui" id="131"><span></span>Item 7</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you try to create global variable AS startPos in the start function, and call that variable again when you stop moving the item?
You need to remove 'var' in order to create global variable.
You can also save the 'start' position in the object itself in the start function: 'this.startPos=ui.start.index()'.

Answer (score 1):

All the infos needed are available in the `stop` event.

- `ui.item` is the item you've moved around.
- `ui.item.prev()` / `ui.item.next()` is the item which has been "replaced"

```js
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var moved = ui.item,
                replaced = ui.item.prev();
            
            // if replaced.length === 0 then the item has been pushed to the top of the list
            // in this case we need the .next() sibling
            if (replaced.length === 0) {
                replaced = ui.item.next();
            }
            
            console.log(moved.attr("id"), replaced.attr("id"));
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui" id="125"><span></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui" id="126"><span></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui" id="127"><span></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui" id="128"><span></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui" id="129"><span></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui" id="130"><span></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui" id="131"><span></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```